The condition that $\{1^p, 2^p, \dots, n^p\}$ is a subset-sum-distinct set






I apologize if the following question has already been studied.

Call a set of positive integers $\textit{subset-sum-distinct}$ (or SSD) if all pairwise distinct subsets have unequal sums.


We fix a positive integer $n$. For a positive integer $p$, we set
\[ S(n,p):= \{ k^{p} \,\;\vert\,\; k \in \mathbf{Z}\; \text{and} \; 1 \leq k \leq n\}.\]


It is not difficult to prove the following items:

$\bullet$ There exists $q$ such that $S(n,q)$ is a SSD set.

$\bullet$ If $S(n,r)$ is a SSD set, then so is 
$S(n,r+1)$.


We set
\[ a_n:=\min \{ p \,\;\vert\,\; S(n,p) \;\text{is a SSD set}\}.\]

$\textbf{Example.}$ The values of $a_n$ for $1 \leq n \leq 12$
are as follows:
\[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,4, 5,5,5, 6.\]

$\textbf{Question.}$ Is it possible to give an estimation for
$a_n$? 

For example, we can prove that $a_{20}=8$. This implies that
$\frac{a_{20}}{20}=0.4$. Generalizing this, is it possible to prove $\frac{a_n}{n}\leq 0.4$ for $n\geq 20$?


$\textbf{Added on November 5, 2024}$

I replace the SSD-question by a question about definite integral: 

We still fix a positive integer $n$. We define the function
\[ f_n: (0,\infty) \to \mathbf{R}\]
by
\[ f_n (u):= \int_0^1 \prod_{j=1}^n \left( \sin^2 (\pi j^u x)\right) dx.\]

By some computations, we can prove
the following:

$\textbf{Lemma.}$ As above, let $p$ be a positive integer. Then,  
\[ \text{\(S(n,p)\) is a SSD set} \Longleftrightarrow f_n(p)=\frac{1}{2^n}.\]

$\textbf{Property of $f_n$.}$ $\;$ As $u$ becomes large, the graph of $f_n$ vibrates intensively (similarly to Dirac's delta function
$\displaystyle{\frac{\sin (mx)}{\pi x}}$).


$\textbf{Modified Question .}$

1. Using the lemma, can we obtain a information on $p$ for which $S(n,p)$ is a SSD set? 

2. In particular, can we prove "the item" whose mon-triviality was pointed out by Ewan?





Showing that "If $S(n,r)$ is a SSD set, then so is $S(n,r+1)$" does not seem that easy to me, how do you do it ?

Dear Ewan, Thank you for your comment. I am sorry that I misunderstood something. The sentence "If S(n,r) is a SSD set, then so is S(n,r+1)" is not clear.
